# How to solve import error for pandas using iPython Notebook on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, pandas, xlwings

I'm trying to import pandas while using iPython.  My overall purpose is to use XLwings.

I'm on Windows 7 and have used Anaconda to install Python, pandas and all the dependencies.

Here is my code:

```
from pandas import DataFrame
```

Which gives:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-26dfcabfb474> in <module>()
----> 1 from pandas import DataFrame

C:\Users\Accounting\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py in <module>()
     11                       "pandas from the source directory, you may need to run "
     12                       "'python setup.py build_ext --inplace' to build the C "
---> 13                       "extensions first.".format(module))
     14 
     15 from datetime import datetime

ImportError: C extension: hashtable not built. If you want to import pandas from the source directory, you may need to run 'python setup.py build_ext --inplace' to build the C extensions first.
```

Can anyone with experience of using Python/pandas in iPython on Windows help me understand how to solve this error?

Specifically where do I run "python setup.py build_ext --inplace"?

Thanks!

Comment: you don't. There is a bug in older versions (of conda) where if you had updated pandas WHILE it was being used it didn't update correctly. Try closing all python processes, then ``conda remove pandas; conda install pandas``

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As posted by Jeff in the comments:

There is a bug in older versions (of conda) where if you had updated pandas WHILE it was being used it didn't update correctly. Try closing all python processes, then

```
conda remove pandas

conda install pandas
```

Comment: I am experiencing this in Ubuntu 14.04, and closing Python processes, `conda remove pandas` then re-installing does not seem to fix it. After re-installing (**with conda**) I get this "ImportError: C extension: No module named builtins not built. If you want to import pandas from the source directory, you may need to run 'python setup.py build_ext --inplace' to build the C extensions first."

Answer (score 0):

I found while installing packages (most from Christoph Gohlke), sometimes you have to use "pip install name of .whl" (in proper path to package) and initially adding a "C:/miscutilities" to Environmental Variables PATH if it wouldn't install from the Anaconda -> Lib -> site-packages. Then some other packages I used conda.