# Failed to execute python script built using PyInstaller (ModuleNotFoundError)

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am trying to turn a .py file into .exe so that it's runnable on other computers without python. I followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UZX5kH72Yx4&ab_channel=TechWithTim) tutorial, installed pyinstaller then ran the command `pyinstaller --onefile IRV.py` without the `-w` since my program runs in the console. It successfully built the .exe file but when I run it it immediately closes even though the program itself asks for input at the beginning. It uses a bunch of .txt and .xslx files from the folder of the .py file so I dragged the .exe out of the dist folder but it still gives the same error. I managed to make a quick print screen before it closes and it gives me this error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdP6h.jpg

The script doesn't even work if I double click the .py file. However it runs perfectly fine if I open up the .py file in an IDE like Spyder. When I run the .exe file it opens up the cmd for a few seconds with nothing written on it and then quickly writes that error I managed to screenshot and then closes. If I double click the .py though it instantly closes without the wait or the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Pyinstaller didn't find the libraries or modules you imported. In the build folder that was deleted in the tutorial, there's a text document that shows warnings for libraries that aren't found by the pyinstaller. You may need to check that.

This Q&A mentioned a problem that is related to your Question: [No module error when running python script from command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37050336/13045884)