# Pandas not working in R Shiny App (''python setup.py build_ext --inplace" error)

Tags: python, r, pandas, numpy, conda

I have an R shiny app whose `server.R` file calls a number of python scripts, all of which depend on importing pandas. All of the packages that the python files import (including pandas) exist inside the directory that I am trying to deploy to `shinyapps.io`.

When I run the app, I get the following error when the R script calls one of the python scripts (the calls are made using the `system()` function):

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "saved_songs.py", line 4, in 
>      import pandas as pd
>    File "/Users/eleh/spotify/pandas/**init**.py", line 32, in 
>      "the C extensions first.".format(module))
>
> ImportError: C extension: _thread not built. If you want to import pandas from the source directory, you may need to run 'python setup.py build_ext --inplace --force' to build the C extensions first.

I have seen other questions about this error but nothing has worked for me so far, and I'm not sure where to run this command from since setup.py does not exist in the pandas package. I've copied all pandas packages and dependencies from /Users/eleh/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages to the R shiny directory. I've also tried uninstalling and reinstalling pandas (both with pip and condas). The packages currently in the directory are:

- numpy
- dateutil
- numpy-1.9.2-py2.7.egg-info
- numpydoc
- six-1.10.0.dist-info
- numpydoc-0.5-py2.7.egg-info
- six.py
- packages
- pandas
- python_dateutil-2.4.2-py2.7.egg-info
- pytz
- lxml
- requests

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30945272/how-to-solve-import-error-for-pandas-using-ipython-notebook-on-windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30945272/how-to-solve-import-error-for-pandas-using-ipython-notebook-on-windows)?

Comment: I tried the suggestions on the above page without success. I'm on a Mac, and the R directory I use for my Shiny app runs every python script like so: /usr/bin/python name_of_file.py (rather than /Users/eleh/anaconda/bin/python). I'd like to know how to either change my pandas files so they are compatible with the R directory, or change the R directory such that it is compatible with anaconda (not sure if this is possible)